# How to Make a Java RMI Call via Internet to a Server

Tags: java, rmi

I tried a simple java rmi program where the client makes a remote call to a server and the server returns a String. it worked perfectly with two computers connected via lan. how can i implement a remote call by a client which is not connected to the server via lan but the server and client are both connected to the internet? I tried the following simple code by changing 'localhost' in Client.java to server's ip address. Didn't Work. what do i need to make such a remote call?

//Remote Interface -> MyInterface.java

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface MyInterface extends Remote
{
    public String SaySomething() throws RemoteException;
}
```

//Client.java

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;

public class Client
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        System.setProperty( "java.security.policy", "client.policy" );
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
                    System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        try {
                        String name = "MyInterface";
                        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost",4501);
                        MyInterface mi = (MyInterface) registry.lookup(name);
            System.out.println(mi.SaySomething());
                } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

//Server.java

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server implements MyInterface
{
    public Server()
    {
        super();
    }
    public String SaySomething()
    {
        return "Server Speaking";
    }
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        System.setProperty( "java.security.policy", "server.policy" );
        if(System.getSecurityManager() == null)
           System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
            try {
                        String name = "MyInterface";
                        MyInterface mi = new Server();
                        MyInterface stub =(MyInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(mi,4501);
                        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4501);
                        registry.rebind(name, stub);
                        System.out.println("Server bound");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("oops");
                }
    }
}
```

**I get the following exception:**
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "x.x.x.x:4501" "connect,resolve")
       at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
       at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:574)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
       at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
       at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:208)
       at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
       at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
       at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
       at Client.main(Client.java:14)

Comment: It would help if you provided more details about how it failed... "didn't work" is a bit too vague. Also, what have you tried to solve or investigate the problem?

Comment: I would add that RMI is not a secure protocol. So please don't go around sending credit card details :).

Comment: Sorry, I am a little rusty with port numbers but isn't 4501 too low for general over-the-internet use, I thought that ports below a certain number were reserved. Maybe try a higher port like 10101 or something.

Comment: Which is the content of client.policy file?

Comment: grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
Both for client and server

Comment: Clearly that .policy file isn't in effect. Run your client with -Djava.security.debug=access,failure to see what security policies *are* in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using the codebase feature you don't need the security manager for RMI. Remove it.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably check your access.

If your server is your home PC, you should check to make sure that your router allows incoming connections (it is blocked by default).

If your server is an office PC, then it may be blocked by a firewall.

Comment: i dont have a rounter. i have a dial-up internet connection. what should i do

Comment: Assuming you are running Windows, do you have Windows Firewall running?

Comment: i disabled firewall while running this application. i tried setting up a vpn using hamachi between two computers. after that i changed the 'localhost' in client code to virtual ip address of server. then the program worked till registry, i.e., registry stub got created but exception came at the lookup line. is there some problem of port opening?

Comment: It's an AccessPermission failure from the SecurityManager. Nothing to do with firewalls whatsoever. -1